# AttributeError: 'SpatialReference' object has no attribute 'ImportfromWkt'

Tags: gdal, attributeerror

I just started using gdal. I'm trying to get longitude and latitudes from pictures. This is what I have so far. This gives me an attribute error. Anyone know how to fix the attribute error?

```
    from osgeo import osr
    import numpy
    import gdal
    ds = gdal.Open(r"path")
    prj = ds.GetProjectionRef()
    oldcs = osr.SpatialReference()
    oldcs.ImportfromWkt(prj)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b32399e41073> in <module>
      7 prj = ds.GetProjectionRef()
      8 oldcs = osr.SpatialReference()
----> 9 oldcs.ImportfromWkt(prj)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\osgeo\osr.py in <lambda>(self, name)
    354     __setattr__ = lambda self, name, value: _swig_setattr(self, SpatialReference, name, value)
    355     __swig_getmethods__ = {}
--> 356     __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, SpatialReference, name)
    357     __repr__ = _swig_repr
    358 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\osgeo\osr.py in _swig_getattr(self, class_type, name)
     78     if method:
     79         return method(self)
---> 80     raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (class_type.__name__, name))
     81 
     82 

AttributeError: 'SpatialReference' object has no attribute 'ImportfromWkt'
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo. The method is `ImportFromWkt()` (note the capitalized F).

```
oldcs.ImportFromWkt(prj)
```

It is a good idea to use an IDE that offers autocomplete features so you can easily avoid this type of mistakes in the future as well as check all the methods that a specific object can call.